# ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5, mysqldump

There is a SAN mounted 1TB partition for Mysql backups in our server with version 5.0.45-log. From two days, im seeing the log entries ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full. The mysqldump is 3.2GB. I assue that it will create an issue while restoring this DB.

```
  1. Can we analyse the Dump / backup inconsistancy without restoring (testing), if so how ?
  I can aware that this error is occurring due to one table named user_analysis.
```

Even a single table error leads to dump / backup incosistancy which leads to restoration failure. In my case daily backup is completing successfully. This issue might also cause due to insufficient space. But i had aroung 82GB free space in the SAN mounted partition. I could also see innoDB free space in the table.

```
  blade_server:master_db> show table status like "user_analysis"\G
  *************************** 1. row ***************************
                   Name: user_analysis
                 Engine: InnoDB
                Version: 10
             Row_format: Compact
                   Rows: 1312878
         Avg_row_length: 33
            Data_length: 43581440
        Max_data_length: 0
           Index_length: 19447808
              Data_free: 0
         Auto_increment: 1312171
            Create_time: 2011-11-25 03:00:41
            Update_time: NULL
             Check_time: NULL
              Collation: utf8_general_ci
               Checksum: NULL
         Create_options: 
   Comment: InnoDB free: 13190144 kB; (`user_id`) REFER `master_db/users`(`user_id`)
      1 row in set (0.01 sec)

      blade_server:master_db> select (13190144) /1024/1024;
      +-----------------------+
      | (13190144) /1024/1024 |
      +-----------------------+
      |           12.57910156 | 
      +-----------------------+
      1 row in set (0.00 sec)

    Where we had around 12.57 GB InnoDBfree space.

 InnoDB is per file :

   mysql> show variables like "innodb_data_file_path"\G
   *************************** 1. row ***************************
      Variable_name: innodb_data_file_path
      Value:
```

ibdata1:1000M;ibdata2:1000M;ibdata3:1000M;ibdata4:1000M;ibdata5:1000M;ibdata6:1000M;ibdata7:1000M;ibdata8:1000M;ibdata9:1000M;ibdata10:1000M;ibdata11:1000M;ibdata12:1000M

```
 2. What could be the root cause to this error ? I dont have any diskspace issues.
    Where can we pin point for this error ?

 3. Will table is full" triggering in logs due to too low maximum size
    for"innodb_data_file_path".
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set aside, 12000M for your InnoDB DataFiles (ibdata1...ibdata12). The only possible way for you to have this error is if all 12000M of InnoDB DataFiles have no more room to accommodate new rows into it. How is that possible?

There are four types of information that reside in InnoDB DataFiles

- Table Data Pages
- Table Index Pages
- Table MetaData
- MVCC Data

[**MVCC is Multiversion Concurrency Control**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). This facilitates ACID Compliance and Transaction Isolation for every SQL transaction, whether it is a single SQL statement or a block of SQL Statements. Whenever you run SQL against InnoDB Tables, that will definitely involve transaction control thus introducing new MVCC Data. Even if you do not execute START TRANSACTION...COMMIT/ROLLBACK paradigms in your application, AUTOCOMMIT is on by default. That will cause InnoDB to write MVCC Data around any data you are reading and/or writing. If there is enough MVCC in the InnoDB DataFiles, it could potentially block InnoDB row data of a certain length from being written.

You have three options to make this go away:

**OPTION 1 : Add one or more InnoDB DataFiles to innodb_data_file_path**

innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:1000M;ibdata2:1000M;ibdata3:1000M;ibdata4:1000M;ibdata5:1000M;ibdata6:1000M;ibdata7:1000M;ibdata8:1000M;ibdata9:1000M;ibdata10:1000M;ibdata11:1000M;ibdata12:1000M;ibdata13:1000M;ibdata14:1000M

**OPTION 2 : Add autoextend to the laste InnoDB DataFile in innodb_data_file_path**

innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:1000M;ibdata2:1000M;ibdata3:1000M;ibdata4:1000M;ibdata5:1000M;ibdata6:1000M;ibdata7:1000M;ibdata8:1000M;ibdata9:1000M;ibdata10:1000M;ibdata11:1000M;ibdata12:1000M:autoextend

**OPTION 3 : Cleanup the InnoDB Infrastructure**

This would be the most enduring solution because there is an option to keep Table Data Pages and Table Index Pages from ever entering the InnoDB DataFiles. You would have to set this option in my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb-file-per-table
```

This creates a separate tablespace (.ibd) file for each InnoDB table create after you restart mysql with this new option. Just putting in the option and restart mysql will not create the tablespace file. The added bonus for doing this is that you can collapse the innodb_data_file_path to the default:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
```

[I wrote up instructions on StackOverflow on how to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4056261/491757)

Comment: There is scheduled cron job which was prepared for QA, where it will connect to the remote Db using mysqlclient, drop the Database and fetech the last night compressed Db and uncompress it execute the dump script. This error is generating in logs while executing dump script remotely. So how can we restore the dump, in this case which was inconsistant.