# MySQL Index creation failing on table is full

Tags: mysql, innodb, index

UPDATE: tl;dr: The problem was MySQL uses the `TMPDIR` when creating indexes. And my `TMPDIR` was the one running out of disk space.

Original Q:

I'm trying to add an index to an InnoDB table, and getting a `table is full error`.
I have enough disk space and the MySQL configuration has a file-per-table=1. The table data is 85GB and I assume the index will be around 20GB - 30GB and I have much more disk space than that. I'm also using ext3 so I don't feel there's any problem with the file size limit from the OS point of view.

The logged error looks like this:

```
140616 13:04:33  InnoDB: Error: Write to file (merge) failed at offset 3 1940914176.
InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 970752 were written.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 0.
InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
InnoDB: Error number 0 means 'Success'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
140616 13:04:33 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: The table 'my_table' is full
```

What is causing this and how can I resolve?

The create table:

```
`CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
 `uid_from` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `uid_to` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `counter` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `updated` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uid_to`,`uid_from`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`
```

As is the Data is 87.4GB and I estimate there are around 1.5B rows.

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';
Variable_name   Value
tmpdir  /tmp

[root@web ~]# df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       40G   24G   14G  64% /
```

Comment: "InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded." - have you checked that? Are you using ext2? ext3? xfs? Checked the quotas for the user?

Comment: @Phil Checked both. I'm using ext3 and am almost positive there isn't a problem with disk space. Hunch is it's got something to do with a log reaching his limit or something, but no idea really how to verify and fix.

Comment: I wonder what file "(merge)" is?

Comment: @akuzminsky hmm I have no idea. I only ran a new index creation from PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: +1 for TMPDIR, that was the issue on my server as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please don't fooled by the error message `The table 'my_table' is full`. This rare scenario has absolutely nothing to do with diskspace. This table full condition has to do with the internal plumbing of InnoDB.

First, take a look at this diagram of the InnoDB Architecture

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Please note that the system tablespace (the file ibdata) only has [**128 Rollback Segments**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_rollback_segments) and 1023 Rollback Slots Per Rollback Segment. This places limits on the size of a transaction's rollback capacity. In other words, if a single rollback segment needs more than 1023 slots to support a transaction, the transaction will hit that `table is full` condition.

Think of [the restaurant Red Lobster in New Jersey](http://www.yelp.com/biz/red-lobster-secaucus). It may have a capacity of 200 people. If the restaurant is full, a line of people may go outside to wait. If the people on the line get impatient, they may leave because the restaurant is full. Obviously, the solution would not be to make New Jersey bigger (or getting more diskspace). The solution would be to make the Red Lobster restaurant bigger. That way you can increase the seating capacity to, let's say, 240. Even with that, a line may form outside if more than 240 people decide to come to Red Lobster.

Just to give you an example, I had a client with 2TB of system tablespace and [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) was disabled. (346G for ibdata1, the reset for ibdata2). I ran this query

```
SELECT SUM(data_length+index+length) InnoDBDataIndexSpace
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';
```

Next, I substracted InnoDBDataIndexSpace from the sum of the filesizes for ibdata1 and ibdata2. I got two things that shocked me

- There was 106GB remaining inside the system tablespace.
- I got this same `Table is Full` condition

This means that the 106GB was using for InnoDB's internal plumbing. The client was using ext3 at the time.

The solution for me was to add ibdata3. I discussed this in my old post [How to solve "The table ... is full" with "innodb_file_per_table"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/how-to-solve-the-table-is-full-with-innodb-file-per-table/43577#43577)

I have discussed this in other posts as well

- `Mar 31, 2014` : [mysql directory grow to 246G after one query, which failed due to table is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62107/mysql-directory-grow-to-246g-after-one-query-which-failed-due-to-table-is-full/62108#62108)
- `Nov 25, 2011` : [ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/error-1114-hy000-at-line-6308-in-file-the-table-user-analysis-is-full/8412#8412)

Keep in mind that this condition can happen even if [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) was enabled. How? [Rollbacks and Undo Logs are the source of uncontrolled spikes is growth for ibdata1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40730/how-can-innodb-ibdata1-file-grows-by-5x-even-with-innodb-file-per-table-set/40734#40734).

## YOUR ACTUAL QUESTION

Since your are adding an index to a table and getting `Table is Full`, the table must be huge and cannot fit inside a single rollback segment. You must do the following:

## STEP 01

Get the data into a dump file

```
mysqldump --no-create-info mydb mytable > table_data.sql
```

## STEP 02

Login to MySQL and run this

```
USE mydb
CREATE TABLE mytable_new LIKE mytable;
ALTER TABLE mytable_new ADD INDEX ... ;
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME mytable_old;
ALTER TABLE mytable_new RENAME mytable;
```

## STEP 03

Load the table with the additional index with the data

```
mysql -Dmydb < table_data.sql
```

That's all.

See, the problem is that the ALTER TABLE will try to inject all the rows in your huge table as a single transaction. Using the mysqldump will insert the data into table (now with a new index) thousands of rows at a time, not all the rows in a single transaction.

Don't worry about `what if this doesn't work?` The original table will be named `mytable_old` in case of anything. it can serve as a backup. You can drop the backup when you know the new table works for you.

## Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2014-06-16 11:13 EDT

If you are worried about the dump of the data bigger huge, just gzip it.

You can do the same steps, but as follows

## STEP 01

Get the data into a dump file

```
mysqldump --no-create-info mydb mytable | gzip > table_data.sql.gz
```

## STEP 02

Login to MySQL and run this

```
USE mydb
CREATE TABLE mytable_new LIKE mytable;
ALTER TABLE mytable_new ADD INDEX ... ;
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME mytable_old;
ALTER TABLE mytable_new RENAME mytable;
```

## STEP 03

Load the table with the additional index with the data

```
gzip -d < table_data.sql.gz | mysql -Dmydb
```

or

```
gunzip < table_data.sql.gz | mysql -Dmydb
```

## UPDATE 2014-06-16 12:55 EDT

I just thought of another aspect with regard to this issue.

Since you are doing DDL and not DML, it is possible that this is not InnoDB internal plumbing. Since [DDL cannot rollback for InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cannot-roll-back.html), the issue has to be external plumbing. Where is this external plumbing getting clogged? I suspect the temp folder for the OS. Why?

```
140616 13:04:33  InnoDB: Error: Write to file (merge) failed at offset 3 1940914176.
InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 970752 were written.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 0.
InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
InnoDB: Error number 0 means 'Success'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
140616 13:04:33 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: The table 'my_table' is full
```

See the `disk quota exceeded` ? Where is this disk quota being imposed ?

Run this query

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';
```

You said it's `/var/lib/mysqltmp`

Now, run this in the OS

```
df -h /var/lib/mysqltmp
```

Something tells me that the space for `/var/lib/mysqltmp` was running out After all, you only have 14G free. In the eyes of the DDL (to create the index), a rollback happened, not in the ibdata1 file, but in the `tmpdir` location. If `/var/lib/mysqltmp` is not mounted anywhere, then the temp data is being written in the root partition. If `/var/lib/mysqltmp` is mounted somewhere, then that mount is being filled with row data. In either case, there is not enough room to complete the DDL.

You have two options here

## OPTION #1

You could also create a large disk (perhaps with 100+GB) and mount `/var/lib/mysqltmp` on that large disk.

## OPTION #2

My 3-step suggestions should still work, even with the limited diskspace you have

## COMMENTARY

It's a shame the error message you posted says

```
InnoDB: Operating system error number 0.
InnoDB: Error number 0 means 'Success'.
```

This means the OS is just fine. It also there doesn't exist any associated error number for this situation.

There is another thing you should know. [The MySQL Documentation says that Fast Index Creation for InnoDB still goes to disk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-create-index-limitations.html):

> During index creation, files are written to the temporary directory
>   ($TMPDIR on Unix, %TEMP% on Windows, or the value of --tmpdir
>   configuration variable). Each temporary file is large enough to hold
>   one column that makes up the new index, and each one is removed as
>   soon as it is merged into the final index.
>
> Due to a limitation of MySQL, the table is copied, rather than using
>   “Fast Index Creation” when you create an index on a TEMPORARY TABLE.
>   This has been reported as [**MySQL Bug #39833**](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39833).

## UPDATE 2014-06-16 13:58 EDT

```
[mysqld]
datadir                         = /mnt/cbsvolume1/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                          = /mnt/cbsvolume1/var/lib/mysql
```

Please make sure `/mnt/cbsvolume1/var/lib/mysql` has 100G or more free

Comment: It took me weeks to build the table in the first place from the dump (85GB data). Is there any other way other than doing this all over again? Would you recommend maybe to partition the table?

Comment: Partitioning won't help because the ALTER TABLE to add the index would still attempt to load everything in a single transaction. Remember, you are fighting the InnoDB Architecture, not the diskspace. My answer should help you in this case since the mysqldump injects a few thousand rows per INSERT, not an all-or-nothing insert into a temp table with the possibility of a rollback.

Comment: But creating this table will (again) take forever. Any way to run a create index while disabling the rollback option?

Comment: Creating an index is DDL not DML. You cannot change DDL behavior. That's why my post uses DML techniques.

Comment: BTW how many rows does the table have ???

Comment: Added the table structure to the question along with rows count estimation (1B - 1.5B).

Comment: Please post the following : `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';`. Also, goto the OS and run `df -h /tmp`.

Comment: Added your requests to the question. Does he use that space? The data-dir is mapped to a mounted drive with enough free disk space.

Comment: I'll try mounting the tmp dir to the bigger disk the data-dir is on. You got simple directions for that?

Comment: You should shutdown mysql, make your change to `/var/lib/mysqltmp`, and restart mysql.

Comment: Would you suggest to change in `my.cnf`? I currently have this `datadir =/mnt/cbsvolume1/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp` and can change to this:                    `datadir =/mnt/cbsvolume1/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /mnt/cbsvolume1/var/tmp`. Sounds ok?

Comment: Only thing missing if anyone else has the same problem, is making sure the new tmpdir has permissions for mysql. `A chown mysql:mysql /mnt/cbsvolume1/newTmpDir` helped with that for me.